# Open Close Animation for isometric Parking Barrier

Tags: css

**Hey CSS Pros**

I have an Isometric Svg drawing with 3 Parking Barrier's,
my knowledge about css animations are to bad that I can write an opening and closing animation for these barrier's, maybe some of you can give me some hints or information how I can do this.
"Schranken" is the german word for parking barrier =)

```
.schranken1  {
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

.schranken1-rotate {
  transform: rotateZ(300deg) translateX(26px) translateY(28px);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xuLycnjt/2/)

**Update:**

After removing transition and modify the transform prop,
opening and closing works, but with hardcoded values,
and without a smoth animation. Is there a way to remove this hardcoded values and have a smooth animitaton ?

```
.schranken1 {
  transform-origin: bottom; 
}

.schranken1-rotate {
  transform: rotate(300deg) translate(54.8%, 35.7%);
}

.schranken2 {
  transform-origin: bottom; 
}

.schranken2-rotate {
  transform: rotate(300deg) translate(73.4%, 46.3%);

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bunch of different techniques on this with no success. I think unless the fulcrum (assuming that is the correct engineering term) is on the base of the barrier, any transition duration, or timing function (ease, linear, etc.) is going to make the barrier orbit a focus way in the distance and look kind of haywire.

If you could manage the get the barrier to rotate on the base, like in the attached annotated image, you could just use `transition-duration: 1s;` and `transition-timing-function: ease-in-out (or linear, ease, etc);`

[image: annotated image]